# Compiling mod_spnego for Apache 2.4.3 HTTP Server running on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2012, apache2, windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos

Has anyone managed to compile mod_spnego 0.2.0 for Apache 2.4 HTTP Server running on Windows?  I would really like to use mod_auth_kerb 5.4, but from what I've read, it's almost hopeless to compile on Windows.

I am currently running Apache HTTP Server 2.4.3 on a Windows 2008 R2 box.  I'm tring to compile mod_spnego using Visual Studio 2012 and I think that I'm almost there, but I keep getting the following error:

```
mod_spnego.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ap_requires
```

Apparently, the `ap_requires()` function is no longer supported in Apache 2.4.

I've Googled this issue and the best response that I can find is as follows:

> It needs to register an auth provider.  As a simple example, compare
>   the 2.2 and 2.4 versions of the bundled module mod_authz_dbm.c.

To be honest, I have no idea as to how I should proceed.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Any ideas on mod_auth_kerb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended with heavily modifying mod_spnego as the original version was far too unstable. It's now available at https://github.com/ibauersachs/mod_spnego, but it still uses ap_requires.

According to the 2.4 release notes, ap_requires should be replaced by registering a "Require" with ap_register_auth_provider. If you know a bit of C, implementing this should be far easier inside my modified version than in the original version.